# How to shorten time quantum in measuring time difference?

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to measure user reaction time. My code looks like this:

```
int clocks2ms(clock_t range) {
  return (int)((double)range*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

clock_t start = clock(); // start measuring
while(!kbhit()); // wait for keypress
int reaction = clocks2ms(clock()-start); // measure reaction
```

The reaction time is 186ms (+-1ms), 201ms, 216ms etc, so there are equal 15ms gaps. Is there any way to shorten the gaps? I tried to run it with realtime priority

```
start "test" /Realtime "test.exe"
```

but nothing changed. I'd like to get 1ms accurancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a timer with a higher precision like `GetPerformanceCounter()` ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartCounter;
LARGE_INTEGER EndCounter;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartCounter);
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);

// Do stuff...

QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndCounter);

double TimeDelta = (EndCounter.QuadPart - StartCounter.QuadPart) / (double) Frequency.QuadPart;
```

Note that I've omitted error checking for the `Query...` functions in the example code above.

Answer (score 2):

2 approaches to gain more precise answers.

Synchronize the start.  Rather than start *someplace* within a clock tick, start just after a change.  This will typically reduce the "jitter" of the start.   This idea is the better of the 2 - it does not gain a more precise answer but does improve accuracy.

```
clock_t prestart = clock();
clock_t start,end;
while((start = clock()) == prestart);  //
puts("Hit Any Key");
fflush(stdout);
while(!kbhit()); // wait for keypress
end = clock();
int reaction = clocks2ms(end-start);
```

Clock cycles after end sample.  This potentially improves precision, but depends on the stability of the system - that is how much other processing is going on.

```
unsigned count = 0;
...
while(!kbhit()); // wait for keypress
end = clock();
while(end == clock()) count++;
int reaction = clocks2ms(end + (max_cnt_per_tck-count)/max_cnt_per_tck - start);
```

Of course neither of these methods are better than access to a higher precision clock as suggest by @uesp.  They suffer from real time aspects of systems such as the inconsistency in the time to `print()` or interrupts that may occur between this thread's code.  But they do offer some improvement when a more precise time source is not available.

Answer (score 1):

If the time resolution of `kbhit()` is the problem here, then there are a few alternatives you could try:

1. Since the `kbhit()` function is actually [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235390.aspx), you might get better results using the `_kbhit()` function instead.
2. If you are able to compile your project with `ncurses`, there is a `getch()` function that fetches characters without waiting for the return key.
3. [This question at the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html) lists a few other ways of fetching characters from the console that might give better results.